# How to find expansion of slightly modified Coulomb's potential?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, spherical-harmonics

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion_(potential)) I know that,

${{\frac {1}{|\mathbf {r}_1 -\mathbf {r}_2|}}=\sum _{\ell =0}^{\infty }{\frac {4\pi }{2\ell +1}}\sum _{m=-\ell }^{\ell }(-1)^{m}{\frac {r_1^{\ell }}{r_2^{\ell +1}}}Y_{\ell }^{-m}(\theta ,\varphi )Y_{\ell }^{m}(\theta ',\varphi ').}$

where $|r_1|<|r_2|.$ I was wondering if there exists a strategy to find expansions for general potentials, for instance

$$\frac{1}{|r_1-r_2|^{1+\alpha}}, \text{    }\alpha>0$$

or more generally for functions $\phi(|r_1-r_2|)?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual multipole expansion follows from the [Legendre identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Definition_via_generating_function)
$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-2xt+t^{2}}}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }P_{n}(x)t^{n}}
$$
The generalization to arbitrary powers requires the [Gegenbauer identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenbauer_polynomials#Characterizations)
$$
{\frac {1}{(1-2xt+t^{2})^{\alpha }}}=\sum _{{n=0}}^{\infty }C_{n}^{{(\alpha )}}(x)t^{n}
$$
which yields
$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {1}{|\mathbf {x} -\mathbf {y} |^\alpha}}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {|\mathbf {x} |^{k}}{|\mathbf {y} |^{k+\alpha}}}C_{k}^{(\alpha/2)}\biggl({\frac {\mathbf {x} \cdot \mathbf {y} }{|\mathbf {x} ||\mathbf {y} |}}\biggr)}
$$

You can [write this in terms of spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Addition_theorem), if you wish.

For arbitrary potentials, you can use the fact that the spherical harmonics are a basis, and therefore you can expand
$$
\phi(\vec r_1,\vec r_2)=\sum_{\ell,m\\\ell',m'}c_{\ell,m;\ell',m'}(r_1,r_2) Y_\ell^m(\theta,\phi)Y_{\ell'}^{m'}(\theta',\phi')
$$
where the coefficients are
$$
c_{\ell,m;\ell',m'}(r_1,r_2)=\int \phi(\vec r_1,\vec r_2)(Y_\ell^m(\theta,\phi)Y_{\ell'}^{m'}(\theta',\phi'))^*
$$

Unless you carefully choose $\phi$ to be a special function (e.g., with some interesting symmetries), this expression cannot in general be simplified much further.

Comment: The expansion in spherical harmonic works only when $\alpha=n-2.$ I would like to know what happens when this is not the case. For instance when $n=3$ and $\alpha=1/2?$

Comment: @Student I'm not sure what you mean. The spherical harmonics are a basis, you can always express anything in terms of them. The harmonics work for any choice of $\alpha$. The resulting expression might not be particularly clean, but it will be correct nevertheless.